# javascript Object.prototype VS Anything.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm confused with javascript's Object.prototype and Anything.prototype.

In chrome console, i have code below:

[image]

My questions:

1. The default prototype for any function is an instance of Object. Is it right?
2. If 1 is true. So, both Anything.prototype and Object.prototype are an instance of Object. Object.prototype is an instance with its `__proto__` === null. Therefore, Object.prototype is a special instance at the top of prototype chain. Can i understand like this?

Answer (score 2):

> The default prototype for any function is an instance of Object.

Yes, the `.prototype` property of any `function` holds an object that inherits from `Object.prototype`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Anything.prototype) === Object.prototype // true
```

> So, both `Anything.prototype` and `Object.prototype` are an instance of Object.

I would not say that `Object.prototype` is an *instance* of `Object`, since it defines what that is - and it does not inherit from `Object.prototype`, as you say yourself:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null // true
Object.prototype instanceof Object // false, because
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) // false (obviously)
```

> Therefore, `Object.prototype` is a special instance at the top of prototype chain.

Yes, though I'd say the *top* of every prototype chain is `null`.

Comment: Specifically, `Object.prototype` is [...an immutable prototype exotic object...](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object) whose \[\[Prototype\]\] internal slot is `null`. So indeed, not an instance of `Object`, although it's an object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Being exotic doesn't mean it can't be an `instanceof Object`, but yes, it's very special indeed.

Comment: I didn't say it did. But with its [[Prototype]] slot being null, it's not an instanceof Object.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had the emphasis on the link, since I already stated in my answer that it's `null`. But enough misunderstandings on this page!